# Comparing 3 or more correlation coefficients in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to compare 3 or more correlation coefficients quickly and efficiently in R? I am aware of the `cocor` package for comparing 2 correlation coefficients, but I am looking for a way to run all of the pairwise comparisons at once instead of doing each one individually.

This type of pairwise correlation coefficient comparison was described in the following journal article:

Levy, K.J. 1977. Pairwise comparisons involving unequal sample sizes associated with correlations, proportions or variances. Br. J. Math. Stat. Psychol. 30:137-139.

I want to compare correlation coefficients by using the following code to generate p-values for each pairwise comparison:

```
p_Value = (2*(1-pnorm(abs(((0.5*log((1+r1)/(1-r1)))-(0.5*log((1+r2)/(1-r2))))/(((1/(n1-3))+(1/(n2-3)))^0.5)))))
# r1 = first correlation coefficient in the comparison
# r2 = second correlation coefficient in the comparison
# n1 = number of observations that went in to generating r1
# n2 = number of observations that went in to generating r2
```

The above code first converts correlation coefficients to z-scores, then calculates the difference between them (weighted by the number of observations), and finally determines the p-value.

Here is a sample data set:

```
Relationship <- c("A", "B", "C")
CorrCoeff <- c(0.985, 0.743, 0.430)
CorrCoeff <- as.data.frame(cbind(Comparison, CorrCoeff))
CorrCoeff$nSamples <- 32
> CorrCoeff
  Relationship CorrCoeff nSamples
1            A     0.985       32
2            B     0.743       32
3            C      0.43       32
```

The output I would like is:

```
> Results
  Pairwise_Comparison      p_Value
1                 A-B 1.543237e-08
2                 A-C 4.352074e-14
3                 B-C    0.0582968
```

Or, even better, the function I'm looking for could assign separation lettering to the correlation coefficients:

```
> Separation_Lettering
  Relationship Letter
1            A      a
2            B      b
3            C      b
```

Again, I can generate these results using functions in the `cocor` package, but I'd like to be able to run this test on more than just one pairwise comparison at a time.

Thank you!

Comment: Compare them how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function (`Comparing_Correlation_Coefficients`) that does just this using only base R functions. It takes 6 arguments (the first 3 are required):

`Correlation_Coefficients`: a numeric vector containing the correlation coefficients to be analyzed

`Numbers_of_Observations`: a numeric or an integer vector containing the numbers of observations that went in to each of the corresponding correlation coefficients

`Identifiers`: a character or a factor vector containing names to identify each corresponding correlation coefficient

`Data_Frame`: an optional data frame to include such that column names can be supplied for the first three arguments (the data frame that these columns are from should be provided for this `Data_Frame` argument)

`Alpha = 0.05`: a value of alpha against which significance can be tested (the default is `0.05`)

`Control_for_Experimentwise_Error = TRUE`: an argument specifying whether or not this function should give conservative estimates (i.e., holding the experimentwise error rate at the given value of alpha) or liberal estimates (i.e., using the given value of alpha for each pairwise comparison); the default, `TRUE`, holds the experimentwise error rate at alpha and calculates the comparisonwise error rate based on the number of pairwise comparisons

Here is a link to the GitHub page for this function:

https://github.com/davidblakneymoore/A-Function-for-Comparing-Multiple-Correlation-Coefficients-in-R

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

You can create correlation matrix. here is an example,

```
# Load data
data("mtcars")
my_data <- mtcars[, c(1,3,4,5,6,7)]
# print the first 6 rows
head(my_data, 6)
```

Output of above code:

```
                   mpg disp  hp drat    wt  qsec
Mazda RX4         21.0  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02
Datsun 710        22.8  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44
Hornet Sportabout 18.7  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02
Valiant           18.1  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22
```

Now create correlation matrix by command:

```
res <- cor(my_data, method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
# or just by using res <- cor(my_data)
round(res,2)
```

Output of above program:

```
       mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec
mpg   1.00 -0.85 -0.78  0.68 -0.87  0.42
disp -0.85  1.00  0.79 -0.71  0.89 -0.43  
hp   -0.78  0.79  1.00 -0.45  0.66 -0.71
drat  0.68 -0.71 -0.45  1.00 -0.71  0.09
wt   -0.87  0.89  0.66 -0.71  1.00 -0.17
qsec  0.42 -0.43 -0.71  0.09 -0.17  1.00
```